# How can a third party Smart Card reader talk to a HID iCLASS card?

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, winscard

I am attempting to use a Broadcom contactless smard card reader to read a HID iCLASS card using [PC/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) and `<winscard.h>`.

I can successfully read the card's serial number by calling winscard's [SCardTransmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit) function with the APDU `FF CA 00 00 00`; however, **I cannot figure out how to extract and decrypt the iCLASS card's contents.**

According to HID's [OMNIKEY developer guide](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-03296_a.0_-_omnikey_5422_sw_dev_guide.pdf) chapter 12, one can start a secure session by issuing an APDU with INS 0x72. Once the secure session is established, they can read the card's contents. When I issue the APDU `FF 72 00 68 10 <16-byte key>`, I get a response SP1/SP2 of `6D 00` standing for "INS not supported". This is unsurprising as INS 0x72 is specific to the OMNIKEY readers and not supported by my Broadcom reader. **How do I start the equivalent of a secure session with an iCLASS card using a third party reader?**

Comment: Please note, if possible, exact model of the reader and card.

Comment: Boy, that's the million dollar question. I've contacted my computer manufacturer and they can't tell me what they put into my machine which reflects poorly on the manufacturer. The card is an iCLASS 2k.

Comment: Please share most narrow URL to this model on site of HID global. I get a [tonnes](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-d&ei=vCoSXeqLEZCysAe-0aH4Ag&q=iCLASS+2k+site%3Ahidglobal.com&oq=iCLASS+2k+site%3Ahidglobal.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...76548546.76551142..76551576...0.0..0.128.1032.0j9......0....1..gws-wiz.DbiqEdM5iiU) of results.

Comment: This is a failure of the card driver to deliver the request to the card(only permitting valid requests), **or** the drivers for an "official" reader are translating the request to another value that is sent to the card.